# CentOS 7 hardware error message (abrt-cli)

Tags: linux

I'm relatively new to CentOS 7 and everytime i boot i'm getting an hardware error message (ABRT has detected 17 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since 1464186366"). I've been looking though dmesg, abrt-cli --list and var/log/messages with no luch of what could be the message whatsoever. Could anyone point to WHAT i should be looking for?

These are the outputs for dmesg (http://pastebin.com/2Jhkx3Wn) and abrt-cli --list (http://pastebin.com/yb4aJqiB).

Thanks in advance.